# How can I workaround this inconsistent behavior of rxjs combineLatest with ReplaySubject

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I am struggling with the following example:

```
const r1 = new ReplaySubject(2);
const r2 = new ReplaySubject(2);
r1.next('r1.1');
r1.next('r1.2');
r2.next('r2.1');

combineLatest([r1, r2]).subscribe(console.log);  // -> ["r1.2", "r2.1"]
combineLatest([r2, r1]).subscribe(console.log);  // -> ["r2.1", "r1.1"] -> ["r2.1", "r1.2"]

// r1.1 ----> r1.2 --------
// -------------------> r2.1
```

If I think about it really really long, I can understand but it seems to be more an issue of the actual implementation and not the specification of that function to emit **latest** combinations.

However, what I'm really looking for is something like "`combineEvery`" which will always give me the second output. How can I implement that?

```
// r1.1 ----> r1.2   
// -------------------> r2.1
// -------------------------------> r3.1

[r1.1, r2.1, r3.1] -> [r1.2, r2.1, r3.1]
```

Comment: It seems like your desired behavior is not well defined.  What is the expected output if `r2` emits a second value? Should resulting observable emit 4 values total in that case? What if `r2` and `r3` emit a second value, are there 8 total emissions in that case?

Answer (score 1):

The behavior is a quirk on how *combineLatest* works.  It doesn't emit until there is at least one value from each observable.  It does this by maintaining a counter of initial emissions from the inner observables and preventing the *combineLatest's* emission until the counter matches the count of all observables.

Because the *ReplaySubject* immediately emits its buffered items, only the last element of your array of *ReplaySubject's* will have all its buffered values emitted.  The is because the others' emissions occur before the counter reaches the count of all observables.

```
const r1 = new ReplaySubject(3);
const r2 = new ReplaySubject(3);
const r3 = new ReplaySubject(3);
r1.next('r1.1');
r1.next('r1.2');
r1.next('r1.3');
r2.next('r2.1');
r2.next('r2.2');
r3.next('r3.1');  // only one emission.  Add more you'd get each instance emitted.
combineLatest([r1, r2, r3]).subscribe(console.log);  // -> ["r1.3", "r2.2", "r3.1"]
```

The closest I could come to achieving what you want was to create a rig that first primes the values with the first result, and then puts an artificial wait with a *timer* operator, and then subscribes to the remaining emissions.

```
combineLatest([
  concat(r1.pipe(first()), timer(0).pipe(switchMap(() => r1.pipe(skip(1))))),
  concat(r2.pipe(first()), timer(0).pipe(switchMap(() => r2.pipe(skip(1))))),
  concat(r3.pipe(first()), timer(0).pipe(switchMap(() => r3.pipe(skip(1)))))
]).subscribe(console.log);  
// assuming the values from the previous example are used, then the following is emitted:
// ["r1.1", "r2.1", "r3.1"]
// ["r1.2", "r2.1", "r3.1"]
// ["r1.3", "r2.1", "r3.1"]
// ["r1.3", "r2.2", "r3.1"]
```